# Why putting method as param of getOrDefault, the method will be invoked anyway?

Tags: java, java-8

```java
Map<String, Integer> iMap = new HashMap<>();
iMap.put("a", 1);
Integer a = iMap.getOrDefault("a", getNum());

private Integer getNum() {
    System.out.println("getNum Method has been invoked");
    return 123;
}
```

```
output: getNum Method has been invoked
```

the iMap has key "a", why getNum still has been invoked?

Comment: It's a limited design, since Java does not have lazy evaluation. Use that method only when the parameter is a literal value. You can write your own `getOrDefault(T,Supplier)` or use a 3rd party lib. If you also wanna update the value at the same time, use `computeIfAbsent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `getOrDefault()` evaluates both arguments **before** executing its logic.

If you want to provide an optional part that will be evaluated lazily, then you need Java-8 methods like `merge()` or `computeIfAbsent()`.

```
Map<String, Integer> iMap = new HashMap<>();
iMap.put("a", 1);
Integer a = iMap.computeIfAbsent("a", key -> getNum());
```

Since key "a" is present in the map, the lambda expression will not be executed.

**Note:**

- `computeIfAbsent()` isn't a uniform substitution for `getOrDefault()`. These methods are meant to represent different operations on a map. By its nature, `computeIfAbsent()` is closer to `put()` or `putIfAbsent()` rather than to `getOrDefault()`. The main goal of `computeIfAbsent()` is to **make changes** in a map, while the main goal of `getOrDefault()` is to **retrieve** a value.

Comment: But keep in mind that `computeIfAbsent` will modify the map, in contrast to `getOrDefault`.

Comment: @Holger That's true, it's only a vague similarity, these two methods are meant to represent different operations on a map. By its nature `computeIfAbsent()` is closer to `put()` rather then to `getOrDefault()`. I guess that's worth mentioning in the answer, although the fate of this question is to be removed.

Comment: Being a duplicate does not necessarily imply a question’s removal. You could compare `computeIfAbsent` with `putIfAbsent`, but unfortunately they differ regarding the return value.